# Is it possible to reference a cell above with an ArrayFormula?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is an example situation which I would like to achieve using ArrayFormula:

Column A is the data, column B is the calculation.

[image: desired output]

Here is an implementation without ArrayFormula:

[image: implementation without ArrayFormula]

Here is how I tried to convert it so I wouldn't have to expand it by hand whenever there is a form-submission (which unfortunately inserts a new row instead of adding just the data):

[image: ArrayFormula attempt]

But as you can see this gives me a circular dependency error:

[image: ArrayFormula error]

Which is not strictly true; while the calculations do depend on each other, they never depend on themselves, so it should be possible to calculate them.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or maybe there is a way to make regular formulas expand automatically?

Note: I am using Google Sheets for this, so I am mainly interested in solutions for that tool.